# unable to connect to mongoDB getting error

Tags: php, mongodb

HI I am trying to install mongo database on Ubuntu and after install when I run the command mongo getting this error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.6
connecting to: test
2015-10-11T11:43:29.448+0530 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-10-11T11:43:29.449+0530 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if mongodb service is running with `service mongod status`

If it's not - run `sudo service mongod start`.

[Run MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#start-mongodb)

Comment: NOw I am getting this error Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145

Comment: Is 'service mongod status' reports that service is running now?